# Set HTML dropdown selected option using JSTL

Tags: java, html, jsp, jstl, el

In the same context i have another query

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="prodSKUs">
            <c:forEach items="${productSubCategoryList}" var="productSubCategoryList">
          <option value="${productSubCategoryList}"${productSubCategoryList == productSubCategoryName ? 'selected' : ''}>${productSubCategoryList}</option>
         </c:forEach>
        </select>
```

and the corresponding setting in request is like

```
for(int i=0;i<userProductData.size();i++){
    String productSubCategoryName=userProductData.get(i).getProductSubCategory();
    System.out.println(productSubCategoryName);
    request.setAttribute("productSubCategoryName",productSubCategoryName);

}
```

here i have multiple select drop down ,even though i get the return value from for as two ,in the UI only one data is getting higlighted not the second one,What is wrong in the code ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Assuming that you have a collection ${roles} of the elements to put in the combo, and ${selected} the selected element, It would go like this:

```
<select name='role'>
    <option value="${selected}" selected>${selected}</option>
    <c:forEach items="${roles}" var="role">
        <c:if test="${role != selected}">
            <option value="${role}">${role}</option>
        </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

UPDATE (next question)

You are overwriting the attribute "productSubCategoryName". At the end of the for loop, the last productSubCategoryName.

Because of the limitations of the expression language, I think the best way to deal with this is to use a map:

```
Map<String,Boolean> map = new HashMap<String,Boolean>();
for(int i=0;i<userProductData.size();i++){
    String productSubCategoryName=userProductData.get(i).getProductSubCategory();
    System.out.println(productSubCategoryName);
    map.put(productSubCategoryName, true);
}
request.setAttribute("productSubCategoryMap", map);
```

And then in the JSP:

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="prodSKUs">
    <c:forEach items="${productSubCategoryList}" var="productSubCategoryList">
        <option value="${productSubCategoryList}" ${not empty productSubCategoryMap[productSubCategoryList] ? 'selected' : ''}>${productSubCategoryList}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Comment: It will only be out of the ordering.

Comment: @BalusC: yes that's what was asked for, @sarah: my answer to your next question is ready

Comment: first anwer is usefull, brings me on a idea :D

Answer (score 12):

In Servlet do:

```
String selectedRole = "rat"; // Or "cat" or whatever you'd like.
request.setAttribute("selectedRole", selectedRole);
```

Then in JSP do:

```
<select name="roleName">
    <c:forEach items="${roleNames}" var="role">
        <option value="${role}" ${role == selectedRole ? 'selected' : ''}>${role}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

It will print the `selected` attribute of the HTML `<option>` element so that you end up like:

```
<select name="roleName">
    <option value="cat">cat</option>
    <option value="rat" selected>rat</option>
    <option value="unicorn">unicorn</option>
</select>
```

*Apart from the problem: this is **not** a combo box. This is a dropdown. A combo box is an **editable** dropdown.*

Comment: what if the select was with the attribute "multiple" and they might be more than one selected roles?

Comment: @stunaz: I've already answered this in your own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059922/how-can-i-do-a-multiselect-in-jsp-jstl-with-selected-value

Comment: +1, stumbled across this looking for a more concise version of `<c:if test="${foo = selectedFoo}">selected="selected"</c:if>`.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, I've used ti but found that instead of "selected=${role == selectedRole ? 'selected' : ''}" it should be just ${role == selectedRole ? 'selected' : ''} , at least in my case.

Comment: @NenadBulatovic: Someone edited it later in, I have rolled back it to my original answer.

Answer (score 3):

Real simple. You just need to have the string 'selected' added to the right option. In the following code, ${myBean.foo == val ? 'selected' : ' '} will add the string 'selected' if the option's value is the same as the bean value;

```
<select name="foo" id="foo" value="${myBean.foo}">
    <option value="">ALL</option>
    <c:forEach items="${fooList}" var="val"> 
        <option value="${val}" ${myBean.foo == val ? 'selected' : ' '}><c:out value="${val}" ></c:out></option>   
    </c:forEach>                     
</select>
```