# How can i do a multiselect in jsp/jstl with selected value?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

Hello I have an User with some Roles
User.class

```
public class User {

 private Long id;
 private String firstName;
 private String lastName;

 private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>(0);
```

public Long getId() { return id; }
 public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }

```
 public String getFirstName() { return this.firstName; }
 public void setFirstName(String firstname) { this.firstName = firstname; }

 public String getLastName() { return this.lastName; }
 public void setLastName(String lastname) { this.lastName = lastname; }

 public Set<Role> getRoles() { return this.roles; }
 public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) { this.roles = roles; }
}
```

Role.class

```
public class Role {

 private Long id;
 private String name;

 public Long getId() { return id; }
 public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }

 public String getName() { return name; }
 public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

}
```

in the jsp file i want to make a multiple select that will have all the roles with the selected values (roles that the user have).

I have tried that :

```
<select id="roles" name="roles" multiple="true" size="4">
 <c:forEach items="${allRoles}" var="role">
  <option value="${role.id}" <c:if test="${role.id == roleSelected.id}">selected</c:if> >${role.name}</option>
 </c:forEach>
</select>
```

where allRoles represent all the role, roleSelected represent the user.roles.
but it not working, is there any manner to say something in jstl like  " if role in user.roles then selected " ?
thank for any advise.

---

**Update**:

somehow its not working, i put a logger in that class i have this :

```
 public static boolean contains(Collection<?> collection, Object object) {
  System.out.println("coll = " + collection.toString());
  System.out.println("obj="+ object.toString());
  System.out.println("res="+ collection.contains(object));
     return collection.contains(object);
   }
```

in the log i have this ,it should result true in the second test:

```
coll = [Id :2;Code: TESTName: Temp Manager;Enabled: true;Comment: ;]
obj=Id :1;Code: ADMName: ADMIN;Enabled: true;Comment: For Adminstrators;
res=false
coll = [Id :2;Code: TESTName: Temp Manager;Enabled: true;Comment: ;]
obj=Id :2;Code: TESTName: Temp Manager;Enabled: true;Comment: ;
res=false
coll = [Id :2;Code: TESTName: Temp Manager;Enabled: true;Comment: ;]
obj=Id :3;Code: RHHName: TECHNOMEDIA;Enabled: true;Comment: Dfdf;
res=false
coll = [Id :2;Code: TESTName: Temp Manager;Enabled: true;Comment: ;]
obj=Id :4;Code: RESPONSName: Refd;Enabled: true;Comment: Sdsds;
res=false
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd create an EL function for that.

```
package com.example;

import java.util.Collection;

public final class Functions {

    private Functions() {
        //
    }

    public static boolean contains(Collection<Object> collection, Object item) {
        return collection.contains(item);
    }

}
```

Define it in `/WEB-INF/functions.tld` like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<taglib 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <display-name>Custom Functions</display-name>    
    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <uri>http://example.com/functions</uri>

    <function>
        <name>contains</name>
        <function-class>com.example.Functions</function-class>
        <function-signature>boolean contains(java.util.Collection, java.lang.Object)</function-signature>
    </function>
</taglib>
```

Then you can use it as follows

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://example.com/functions" prefix="f" %>
...
<select name="roles" multiple>
    <c:forEach items="${allRoles}" var="role">
        <option value="${role.id}" ${f:contains(user.roles, role) ? 'selected' : ''}>${role.name}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

---

**Update**: in order to properly compare objects in a collection you have to implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` accordingly. You seem not have done that. Here's a basic example which compares by technical ID:

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    return other instanceof Role && id != null ? id.equals(((Role) other).id) : other == this;
}

public int hashCode() {
    return id != null ? getClass().hashCode() + id.hashCode() : super.hashCode();
}
```

#### See also:

- [HashSet does not recognize same objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692426/hashset-does-not-seem-to-realize-that-two-objects-are-the-same)
- [Understanding equals and hashcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894377/understanding-the-workings-of-equals-and-hashcode-in-a-hashmap)
- [Overriding equals and hashcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)
- [Right way to implement equals and hashcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181339/right-way-to-implement-equals-contract)

Comment: please check my next problem with your solution.