# How to set <option selected> based on an ArrayList?

Tags: jsp, jstl, html-lists, html-select

I have 2 arraylists in JSP that are passed from controller servlet: `allOptionsList` and `alreadySelectedOptionsList`.

I am trying to generate HTML form with `<select>` dropdown and I want to show all items from `allOptionsList` as an `<option>` within `<select>` but, I want for items that are in `alreadySelectedOptionsList` to be shown as `<option selected="selected">`.

This is what I already have:

```
<select name="options" size="20">
     <c:forEach items="${allOptionsList}" var="optionAll">
        <option>${optionAll.optionName}</option>
     </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Basicly I want for option is to be selected if it is already in the `alreadySelectedOptionsList` list. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're targeting a Servlet 3.0 container which supports EL 2.2 feature of invoking methods with arguments (e.g. Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, etc), then you could use `List#contains()` method for this.

```
<select name="options" size="20">
     <c:forEach items="${allOptionsList}" var="optionAll">
        <option ${alreadySelectedOptionsList.contains(optionAll.optionName) ? 'selected' : ''}>${optionAll.optionName}</option>
     </c:forEach>
</select>
```

But if you're targeting an older container which doesn't support invoking methods in EL, then you need to create a custom EL function which does the job. You can find a concrete example in this answer: [How can i do a multiselect in jsp/jstl with selected value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059922/how-can-i-do-a-multiselect-in-jsp-jstl-with-selected-value/4060393#4060393)

Comment: I have done indeed something like what you are suggesting, only in java  because I am using 2.5 container. I have created third object which contains boolen isSelected field. I compared the objects from two lists and for objects that are in both lists, I set isSelected to true. All this new objects are placed in a list, which is then returned to view. It is actually the same solution that you are sugesting.

Answer (score 0):

Use `c:if`

```
<select name="options" size="20">
     <c:forEach items="${allOptionsList}" var="optionAll">
        <c:if test="${optionAll.selected == 'true'}">
            <option>${optionAll.optionName}</option>
        </c:if>
     </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Comment: but I have to compare it to alreadySelectedOptionsList to see if it is already selected. If it is in alreadySelectedOptionsList than it should be printed as "<option selected="selected"> ${optionAll.optionName}"