# EL syntax to check if a set contains a specific Enum value

Tags: jsp, enums, el, enumset

I have an Item object, which has a field that is a Set of ItemTypes:

```
public class Item {
    EnumSet<ItemType> itemTypeSet;

    ...

    public Set<ItemType> getItemTypeSet(){
        return this.itemTypeSet;
    }
}
```

ItemType is of course a simple Enum.

```
public Enum ItemType {
    BOLD, THIN, COOL, ROUND;
}
```

In my JSP I would like to use JSTL to see if an item has a specific ItemType, I tried to use the following three snippets but I get no errors and no results. I'm not sure why all 3 are failing. Could somebody explain, for each of these 3 cases, why the program doesn't work like I think it does, and provide a 4th alternative that's working :)?

```
<c:if test="${item.itemTypeSet.contains('BOLD')}">
    Method 1 works!
</c:if>
<c:if test="${item.itemTypeSet.contains(ItemType.valueOf('BOLD'))}">
    Method 2 works!
</c:if>
<c:if test="${item.itemTypeSet.contains(ItemType.BOLD)}">
    Method 3 works!
</c:if>
```

Important is that the `ItemType` enum is public and not inside another class. It is totally accessible for any other class, including the ones that resolve the EL/JSTL/JSP.

Note that iterating over all values in the enumset works fine:

```
<c:forEach items="${item.itemTypeSet}" var="itemType">
    <p>${itemType}</p>
</c:forEach>
```

gives as result:

```
BOLD
ROUND
```

Comment: For method 3, did you do `<@page import="com.example.ItemType" %>`? (works only in EL 3.0 capable container though (Tomcat 8, etc)

Comment: I tried, but it didn't do much. It gave no errors either. I'm using JBoss 6.4, which I guess has EL 2.2...

Comment: you have ' in method three you should delete it

Comment: @achabahe that's just a typo, it's not actually in the code. I edited my post.

Answer (score 2):

Method 3 will work in EL 3.0 (Tomcat 8, WildFly 8, GlassFish 4, etc and newer) provided that you imported the enum in JSP page context as instructed in [How to reference constants in EL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732608/how-to-reference-constants-in-el)

```
<@page import="com.example.ItemType" %>
```

Method 2 should theoretically work in EL 3.0 too, but it's clumsy as compared to 3.

Method 1 won't work at all as EL is not aware of the generic type of the collection and still assumes it plain `String` due to the `${'...'}` syntax. Basically, it's doing `"BOLD".equals(BOLD)` under the covers which will never pass.

You'd best create a custom EL function on this. For a kickoff example of a custom EL function, head to the answer on this related question: [How can i do a multiselect in jsp/jstl with selected value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059922/how-can-i-do-a-multiselect-in-jsp-jstl-with-selected-value/) You'd like to end up with something like this:

```
<c:if test="${my:containsEnum(item.itemTypeSet, 'BOLD')}">
```

And do the Java magic accordingly in the `containsEnum(Set, String)` function.