# Implement html multiple select in jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, web

```
<select multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

I need to implement a multiple select list. How would i do it? I would be getting a list from backend whose size can vary.

Comment: Are you using taglibs? JSF? @user101: that question is about reading the values on the server. I think the OP is asking how to generate the HTML code to create the multi-select.

Comment: Is [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059922/how-can-i-do-a-multiselect-in-jsp-jstl-with-selected-value) what you're looking for?

Comment: my question is how do i dynamicall render the multiple select box.

Comment: Look at the question I linked - the `<c:forEach ...>` tag should be what you're after.