# Unable to set the HTML dropdown selected option

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

After referring to the post

[Set HTML dropdown selected option using JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682018/set-html-dropdown-selected-option-using-jstl?lq=1)

I have written a `JSP` in the following way.

```
<form name="options" id="options" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/difficulty.do" method="post">
        <div id="difficulty">
            <label style="font-weight: bold; color: gray; margin-left: 16px">Difficulty Level</label><br>
            <select name="difficultyLevel" style="color: gray; margin-top: 5px" onchange="optionChanged()">
                <c:if test="${level == null}">
                    <option value="easy" name="easy" selected>Easy</option>
                    <option value="medium" name="medium">Medium</option>
                    <option value="hard" name="hard">Hard</option>
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="${level != null}">
                    <option value="easy" name="easy" selected=${level == 'easy' ? "selected" : ''}>Easy</option>
                    <option value="medium" name="medium" selected=${level == 'medium' ? "selected" : ''}>Medium</option>
                    <option value="hard" name="hard" selected=${level == 'hard' ? "selected" : ''}>Hard</option>
                </c:if>
            </select>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('select').on({ "focus": function () {
        this.selectedIndex = -1;
    }, "change": function () {
        $('#options').submit();
    }
    });
    </script>
</form>
```

But when the option is selected a servlet is called and the servlet puts an attribute called level into the `JSP` redirects to the same page. When `level` is `not null` I see only `hard` option in the `dropdown list` irrespective of the selected option i.e. `easy, or medium, or hard`. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK that code will generate invalid HTML. Your `<select>` allows a single option being selected, not multiple. So, change the code for selection in `<option>`:

```
<option value="easy" name="easy" ${level == 'easy' ? "selected" : ''}>Easy</option>
<option value="medium" name="medium" ${level == 'medium' ? "selected" : ''}>Medium</option>
<option value="hard" name="hard" ${level == 'hard' ? "selected" : ''}>Hard</option>
```